# How to upgrade the good dependencies?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my dependencies, i can't install any packages. i have this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: Instadating@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.64.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.64.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.60.0" from react-native-modal-patch@0.61.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-modal-patch
npm ERR!   react-native-modal-patch@"^0.61.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/bonnieandcloud/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

My version of react native is 0.64.2

Comment: delete `node_modules`. Add packages with flag `--save`

Comment: Did you try to run with yarn?